# Standard error of two independent studies combined

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, standard-error, survey, clustered-standard-errors

A pollster publishes political surveys, where people declare which of many parties they intend to vote for. They declare the ‘maximum margin of error’ for their surveys. It is defined as the margin of error for a party if 50 percent of the respondents have chosen this party. Using the normal approximation of a binomial distribution, this makes sense: the variance is maximalized at exactly the half-and-half point.

Lets say $n=1000$ and $z=1.96$ (95 %). The normal approximation maximises the confidence interval at $\hat{p}=0.5$:

$$
\hat{p}\pm z\times\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}} = 0.5 \pm 1.96 \times \sqrt{\frac{0.25}{1000}} \approx 0.5 \pm 0.031
$$

So for a survey of 1000 respondents, everyone agrees that the margin of error, defined like this, is $\pm 3.1$ percentage points.

However, this particular pollster are combining two independently executed surveys, each of them independently sampled and then weighted against population means and other parameters. Notably, they weight the respondents' voting preference in the last election against the actual result at the last election, so if only ten percent of respondents voted for a party that actually got twenty percent at the last election, the weight of these respondents is doubled.

Both surveys have 1000 respondents. Now, to the point of the question. The pollster claim that this method, of $2\times 1000$, results in a lower margin of error than one survey of 2000 respondents. They report the margin of error as $\pm 1.7$ percentage points, while $n=2000$ in the above formula would return $\pm 2.2$ percentage points. They say they arrive at this conclusion by dividing the margin of error of the first survey by the square root of the other, ie. $\frac{3.1}{\sqrt{3.1}}=1.76$.

This seems counter-intuitive. If this is possible, why can't a pollster just divide their surveys into tens or hundreds of sub-studies, and gain less variance?

The pollster is not very forthcoming with the maths behind this magic. Does anyone here have an idea of how this is calculated – either why the pollster is right, or a hypothesis about what they are doing wrong?